# Rubyでループが途中で止まってしまう

Tags: ruby

AtCoderのABC294-Cの問題を解くためのコードを書いたのですが、入力を以下の様にすると、16回行われるはずのループが4回で止まってしまいます。

**入力:**

```
3 3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

**作成したコード:**

```
require 'set'
h,w=gets.chomp.split(" ").map(&:to_i)
board=[]
h.times do |i|
    board[i]=gets.chomp.split(" ").map(&:to_i)
end
sets=[]
2**(h+w-2).times do |i|
#    printf("%04b\n",i)
    count=0
    (h+w-2).times do |k|
        if i[k]==1
            count+=1
        end
    end
    unless count==h-1
        next
    end
    flag=true
    pos=[0,0]
    s=Set.new
    s.add(board[0][0])
    (h+w-2).times do |j|
        dir=[0,0]
        if i[j]==1
            dir=[1,0]
        else
            dir=[0,1]
        end
        pos[0]+=dir[0]
        pos[1]+=dir[1]
        d=board[pos[0]][pos[1]]
        if s.include?(d)
            flag=false
            break
        else
            s.add(d)
        end
    end
    if flag==true
        sets.push(s)
    end
end
puts sets.size
```

Comment: ABC294-C ではなく、ABC293-C では? https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc293/tasks/abc293_c?lang=ja

Answer (score 1):

最初のループの始まりを次のようにしてください。これでうまくいくはずです。

```
(2**(h+w-2)).times do |i|
```

解説

`**`は[かなり高い優先順位の演算子](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2foperator.html)ですが、オブジェクトのメソッド呼び出しの`.`の方が(ドキュメントには明記されていませんが)高いです。そのため、`2**(h+w-2).times do |i| ... end`は`2**((h+w-2).times do |i| ... end)`と解釈されます。つまり、ループは`h+w-2`しかおきず、その後(無意味に)2の累乗していることになります。

Answer (score 0):

詳細は見ていないのですが、ぱっと見た感じ `2**(h+w-2).times do |i|` の `2**` の意味がなさそうなのが気になったので、括弧が不足しているのが原因ではないでしょうか。

```rb
2**1.times{p _1}   #=> 0
(2**1).times{p _1} #=> 0 1
```